# Code is not executed after splitChunks added on webpack config

Tags: webpack, webpack-splitchunks

i am trying to split a code in chunks and i face an issue. 
I have a script like

```
import Component1 from 'Libs/component1';
import Component2 from 'Libs/component2';
import Component3 from 'Integrations/component3';

window.myComponent1 = new Component1();
window.myComponent2 = new Component2();
window.myComponent3 = new Component3;
```

The above window.myComponent statements are executed normally and the objects are globally accessible when i dont use the splitChunks.
If add the below config on the webpack

```
optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
```

The the window.myComponent statements are never executed, if i check the created bundles the code is there but never executed.
Why ? What i am doing wrong ?